# Question about exercise 11.5 in TeXbook

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, expansion

In answer to exercise 11.5 there is this comment:

```
\def\\{\if\space\next\ % assume that \next is unexpandable
```

What does this comment mean? If `\next` may be expandable,
must we use the following instead?

```
\def\\{\expandafter\ifx\space\next\ %
```

Can anybody think about an example which illustrates the difference?

Also, the result does not change if we change `\endlist` to just `\end` as follows:

```
-\def\dodolist{\ifx\next\endlist \let\next\relax
+\def\dodolist{\ifx\next\end \let\next\relax
```

```
-\def\endlist{\endlist}
+%\def\end{\endlist}
```

```
-\def\demobox#1{\setbox0=\hbox{\dolist#1\endlist}%
+\def\demobox#1{\setbox0=\hbox{\dolist#1\end}%
```

What is the point of using `\endlist`?

**EDIT**

I think defining a control sequence, which need not be defined, the way 
`\endlist` is defined here, gives the user a way to tell whether a particular name 
is in use, when he chooses a name for a new control sequence.

---

This is the full example:

```
\def\dolist{\afterassignment\dodolist\let\next= }
\def\dodolist{\ifx\next\endlist \let\next\relax
  \else \\\let\next\dolist \fi
  \next}
\def\endlist{\endlist}
\def\hidehrule#1#2{\kern-#1%
  \hrule height#1 depth#2 \kern-#2 }
\def\hidevrule#1#2{\kern-#1{\dimen0=#1
    \advance\dimen0 by#2\vrule width\dimen0}\kern-#2 }
\def\makeblankbox#1#2{\hbox{\lower\dp0\vbox{\hidehrule{#1}{#2}%
    \kern-#1 % overlap the rules at the corners
    \hbox to \wd0{\hidevrule{#1}{#2}%
      \raise\ht0\vbox to #1{}% set the vrule height
      \lower\dp0\vtop to #1{}% set the vrule depth
      \hfil\hidevrule{#2}{#1}}%
    \kern-#1\hidehrule{#2}{#1}}}}
\def\maketypebox{\makeblankbox{0pt}{1pt}}
\def\makelightbox{\makeblankbox{.2pt}{.2pt}}
\def\\{\if\space\next\ % assume that \next is unexpandable
 \else \setbox0=\hbox{\next}\maketypebox\fi}
\def\demobox#1{\setbox0=\hbox{\dolist#1\endlist}%
  \leavevmode\copy0\kern-\wd0\makelightbox}
\demobox{Tough exercise.}
\bye
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For readers who don't find the line:

```latex
\def\\{\if\space\next\ % assume that \next is unexpandable
```

in their TeXbook, it is in the [errata](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/abcde-errata.pdf) published by Donald E. Knuth (“page A311”).

Suppose you do:

```latex
\def\foobar{cat}

\noindent
\demobox{The \foobar\ in the hat}
```

After `\next` has grabbed the `\foobar` token, `\\` will expand to something equivalent to:

```latex
\if\space\next\ %
\else \setbox0=\hbox{\next}\maketypebox\fi
```

with `\next` being `\let`-equal to `\foobar`. According to the documentation of `\if` (TeXbook p. 209), TeX is going to expand tokens following the `\if` until it finds two non-expandable ones. `\space` expands to an explicit space token in one step, so TeX goes on with `\next` (which has the same meaning as `\foobar` at this point), because it needs one more non-expandable token. After `\next` has been expanded, the input is equivalent to:

```
\if〈space token〉cat\ %
\else \setbox0=\hbox{\next}\maketypebox\fi
```

where 〈space token〉 represents an explicit space token (one could define a control sequence that is `\let`-equal to an explicit space token and use it instead of 〈space token〉, see footnote 1 below). Now, TeX has two non-expandable tokens following the `\if`: a space token and a `c` character token (of category 11 under the normal catcode regime). So, the outcome of the `\if` can be decided: it is false because the character codes of a 〈space token〉 and of `c` differ, so TeX will skip to the `\else` clause.

There is no *big* problem so far, though we are going to box the whole `cat` at once instead of each character separately (`c`, `a`, and `t`); but let's back up a little bit. Had we used:

```latex
\def\foobar{ cat}
```

the input would have been equivalent to:

```latex
\if〈space token〉〈space token〉cat\ %
\else \setbox0=\hbox{\next}\maketypebox\fi
```

The test would have been true and TeX would have left `cat\` in the input stream, which is plain wrong, because we were supposed to *test* what we just grabbed in `\next`, not to insert new text!

So, the comment “assume that `\next` is unexpandable” could be rephrased more generally, in my humble opinion, as “assume that `\next` ultimately expands to either (1) exactly one character token or (2) exactly one `\chardef` token or (3) a control sequence token that is `\let`-equal to (1) or (2)”<sup>2</sup> (the character token in (1) is necessarily non-active, because of the “ultimately”). Indeed, you can test that `\demobox` works perfectly when `\next` recursively expands to a single character token, as in:

```latex
\def\myspacei{\myspace}
\def\myspace{\space}

\noindent
\demobox{Abc def\myspacei pU gHi}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Using `\myspacei` here gives the same result as using an explicit space token, because it recursively expands to such a token.

Here is another example that additionally uses a control sequence that recursively expands to a non-space character token:

```latex
\def\myspacei{\myspace}
\def\myspace{\space}

\def\myxii{\myxi}
\def\myxi{\myx}
\def\myx{X}

\noindent
\demobox{Abc def\myspacei pU\myxii gHi}
```

[image: Screenshot with also a non-space character token]

Your proposal:

```latex
\def\\{\expandafter\ifx\space\next\ %
...
```

would also work, as long as `\next` has been `\let`-equal to a space token (explicit or implicit). But it wouldn't work with input containing spaces in the form of macros like `\space` or our `\myspacei` macro defined above. Indeed, `\ifx` distinguishes between character tokens and macros (see specification of `\ifx` p. 210 of the TeXbook).

Finally, although it would work, your replacement of `\endlist` with `\end` does not sound like the best coding style to me, because `\end` is an existing TeX primitive; Knuth chose something more “unique” to mark the end of the text to be worked on. Besides, the name `\endlist` was visibly chosen to match `\dolist`: it is a matter of consistency. See in particular:

```latex
\def\demobox#1{\setbox0=\hbox{\dolist#1\endlist}%
...
```

---

**Footnotes**

1. You can define a control sequence `\stoken` that is `\let`-equal to an explicit space token like this:

   ```latex
   {\def\\{\global\let\stoken= }\\ }% now, \stoken is an implicit space token
   ```

   (adapted from the TeXbook p. 376). Two other ways are given in the TeXbook p. 336 (exercise 24.6):

   ```latex
   \def\\{\let\stoken= }\\ %
   ```

   and

   ```latex
   \def\\#1\\{}\futurelet\stoken\\ \\%
   ```
2. This is in particular the case when `\next` has been `\let`-equal to a non-active character token—which is, I think, the case Knuth had in mind when he used the word “unexpandable” (indeed, a non-active character token, or a control sequence that has been `\let`-equal to such a token, never expands). In other words, the condition “`\next` is unexpandable” from the comment you quoted is a *sufficient condition* for ensuring that the macros behave sanely, and is only a particular case of the more general condition I gave. :-)

Comment: I just added a footnote clarifying why (presumably) Knuth used the word “unexpandable” in the comment you quoted (insofar as I can get a glimpse of what happens in Knuth's mind!).

Comment: You say: "... as \space is a macro ...", but this is not true, because `\expandafter` makes `\space` a space token.

Comment: `\end` is used just as a token here. Knuth uses it a lot. For example, see final example in chapter 20.

Comment: `\space` is defined in plain.tex with `\def\space{ }`. Anything defined with `\def` (or one of its variants) *is* a macro, that is the *definition* of a macro. If you still don't believe me, run `texdef space`. This outputs `\space: macro:-> `.

Comment: NO! See description of `\expandafter` on p. 213

Comment: Using `\end` works... until you do for instance `\demobox{Some\end text}`. Then it fails. That is why it is better to use something really “unique”. In LaTeX2e, `\@nil` is often used for this purpose, and LaTeX3 has other control sequence tokens for this kind of thing.

Comment: What is the problem in the description of `\expandafter` p. 213? It doesn't even use the word “macro”!

Comment: `\if\space\next...` and `\expandafter\ifx\space\next...` produce the same result (at least when `\next` is a simple character token). Run TeX and check.

Comment: `\demobox{Some\endlist text}` also does not work, for that matter.

Comment: I agree for the `\expandafter\ifx\space\next`, I forgot to “do” the `\expandafter`. This is corrected in my answer. Your counter-example with `\endlist` is also correct. My answer contains the reasons that, in my opinion, justify using `\endlist` rather than `\end`.

Comment: Actually, the example works just fine without the `\def\endlist{\endlist}`. Not sure why this `\def` was added at all (considering the object of the exercise).

Comment: I suppose it is a way for Knuth to express “don't ever try to execute `\endlist`, it is not designed for this kind of use”. Since the definition would immediately cause an infinite loop if `\endlist` ever became the next token to process in TeX' s input stream (expanded, expanded again, etc.), it makes it clear that the purpose of this token is different: it is a marker (technically here, an argument delimiter). LaTeX3 quarks are defined in the same way, see `l3quark` in [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf).

Comment: If one tries to execute `\endlist`, TeX directly says `! Undefined control sequence.`, so I still don't really understand what this `\def` is about. Moreover, a comment in the code like `% don't execute \endlist` would be more appropriate for such a small exercise.

Comment: To get `Undefined control sequence`, you must execute it when still undefined... If  I take the file containing the `\demobox` code from yesterday and append `\endlist` right after `\def\endlist{\endlist}` (uncommented!), then running TeX on the file causes an infinite loop, as expected. The cause of the infinite loop can be found by doing `\tracingmacros=1\tracingonline=1\relax` early enough, which shows an endless stream of `\endlist ->\endlist ` expansions. So, this definition is a debugging aid: when you use it in a wrong way, it tells you if you do the `\tracingmacros=1\tracingonline=1`.

Comment: I'd add that defining a quark as a macro expanding to itself is a neat way to 1) convey the information that the macro is to be used as a quark, and 2) ensure that it doesn't have the same meaning (in the TeX sense of this word) as another quark defined using the same technique.

Comment: When one sees some unknown control sequence `\cs`, how does one determine what it is? I would put `\show\cs` to that part of manuscript where I see `\cs`. Thus, if `\show\cs` shows "undefined", I already know that it is not to be expanded. As for "ensuring that different control sequences don't have the same meaning", names of control sequences serve just this purpose (i.e., if you name control sequences with different names, they have different meaning). So, this whole concept of "quark" is strange to me.

Comment: 1) Yes, or that you are using it in a wrong place (some control sequences are only defined inside some environments, for instance). 2) No: `\def\a{}\ifx\a\empty true\else false\fi` prints true. `\a` and `\empty` have different names but the same meaning.

Comment: I think, I get it. See **EDIT** in OP.

Comment: **If** 1) the user has its own definition of `\endlist` (for whatever reason) as `\chardef\endlist=\`\X` 2) this definition is made after or instead of Knuth's one (overrides it) 3) the user has an equivalent definition like `\let\a\endlist` or `\chardef\a=\`\X` **then** `\demobox{Abc \a stuff that won't get boxed}` won't work as expected, even though `\demobox`'s argument respects Knuth's (and therefore my) condition regarding `\next` for every token grabbed from this argument, in particular when `\next` is `\let`-equal to `\a` (`\a` is indeed unexpandable).

Comment: So, in some way, seeing the `\endlist` definition gives a signal that if the user redefines it in some particular ways like shown in my previous comment (too long to put all in one), this may break `\demobox`.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Regarding LaTeX3 quarks, you may find [this question and the corresponding answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493462/do-quarks-have-to-be-defined-as-macros-expanding-to-themselves) helpful.

Answer (score 6):

It means what it says: only unexpandable tokens are allowed in the argument to `\demobox`. More precisely, character tokens or unexpandable control sequences that correspond (via `\chardef` or `\let`) to *printable* characters (including spaces).

If you try

```
\demobox{abc def}

\def\expandable{expandable token}

\demobox{\expandable}
```

you get

[image]

which is probably not what you were expecting. On the other hand, a definition like

```
\def\expandable{ expandable token}
```

would yield something very far from the expectations.

So the `\demobox` macro can be used only with its argument consisting of unexpandable tokens or macros expanding to a *single* unexpandable token.

Also `\chardef` tokens are allowed, as well as implicit character tokens. However `\bgroup` would also be problematic: compare `\demobox{A \bgroup AB\egroup}` with `\demobox{A AB}`, to see the issue.

You might want to extend `\demobox` in various ways, but that's not the object of the exercise.

About your suggestion to redefine `\dolist` to use `\end` instead of `\endlist`: you can do it, if you prefer. Knuth doesn't prefer it; instead he uses a control sequence that's specific to `\dolist` processing. Note that the definition of `\endlist` will produce an infinite loop whenever `\endlist` is expanded (probably by a mistake in the macros using `\dolist`), whereas `\end` wouldn't.

Comment: Actually, the example works just fine without the `\def\endlist{\endlist}`. Not sure why this `\def` was added at all (considering the object of the exercise).

Comment: @IgorLiferenko The `\dolist` macro can be used in other situations.