# Indirectly defined macros: Undefined macro with "@" does not trigger compile error

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, csname

I defined two macros `\newfoo{#1}{#2}` and `\foo{#1}`. The first parameter is used as a key and must be a valid LaTeX macro name (without the backslash). The second parameter is a short piece of text. Using `\newfoo` a key is associated with its text and using `\foo` the text is supposed to be printed, given the previously defined key.

For those familiar with the glossary/-ies package, the commands can best be depicted as a poor-man's version of those, but I need them in other context.

Internally, `\newfoo{#1}{#2}` defines a macro `\foo@#1` and `\foo{#1}` expands to `\foo@#1`. The MWE below works. But I would have expected to get a compile error, if `\foo` is called for a key that has not been defined previously, because `\foo@#1` does not exist. However, compilation proceeds silently and simply expands a non-existing `\foo@#1` into nothing. This behavior is undesired, because misspelled keys should be noted.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\newfoo[2]{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname foo@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\newcommand*\foo[1]{\csname foo@#1\endcsname}

\makeatother

\newfoo{a}{1st letter of alphabet}
\newfoo{b}{2nd letter of alphabet}

\begin{document}

\verb#\foo{a}# is expected to expand to ``\foo{a}''

\verb#\foo{b}# is expected to expand to ``\foo{b}''

\verb#\foo{c}# has not been defined by \verb#\newfoo{c}{...}# and should raise a compile error

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is

```latex
\newcommand*\foo[1]{%
  \ifcsname foo@#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\csname foo@#1\endcsname}%
  {\ERROR}%
}
```

or, using a kernel construction

```latex
\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{foo@#1}{\ERROR}{\csname foo@#1\endcsname}%
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It is a "feature" of `\csname` that previously undefined commands are defined as if `\let` to `\relax` if accessed via `\csname` ... `\endcsname`.  Usually this is unwanted behaviour but it is used in a few places in LaTeX as it is the only way in classic TeX to make a definition in an expansion-only context and so can be used to flag certain things. (It is used for example to trap problematic characters that are encountered during writing a file in `filecontents`.)

Answer (score 1):

To complete a tiny bit [David Carlisle's excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493917/73317), please note that, had you used `\foo{c}` in your example, it would *not* have expanded to “nothing”, because `\relax` really isn't nothing. If you try to expand `\relax`, you get `\relax` because it is unexpandable.<sup>1</sup> But `\relax` can stop things that a macro expanding to nothing wouldn't stop, such as:

- the expansion process when TeX is reading an 〈integer constant〉, 〈octal constant〉, 〈hexadecimal constant〉 or a 〈glue〉 in the form of 〈dimen〉〈stretch〉〈shrink〉;
- the expansion process when TeX is looking for `\noalign` or `\omit` at the beginning of an alignment (`tabular`, `align`...) or at the end of a row (even several space tokens wouldn't stop the search process in this case, but `\relax` does, and this can prevent `\rowcolor` from working in certain situations—see towards the end of [this message](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492400/73317) for instance);
- probably many other things.

So, the `\relax` command doesn't do much<sup>2</sup> when TeX gets to finally digest it deep inside its stomach; but at other levels, it can have quite noticeable effects.

In your example, you can see for yourself that the expansion of `\foo@c` is `\relax` and not an empty expansion by doing two expansion steps before using `\show`: the first step expands `\foo` (which grabs `{c}`) to `\csname foo@c\endcsname` and the second step expands `\csname` (which grabs `foo@c\endcsname`) to `\foo@c`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\newfoo[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname foo@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\newcommand*\foo[1]{\csname foo@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\show\foo{c}
\end{document}
```

which outputs to the terminal:

```
> \foo@c=\relax.
<recently read> \foo@c 

l.12 ...dafter\expandafter\expandafter\show\foo{c}
```

Of course, the following also works:

```latex
\foo{c}%
\makeatletter
\show\foo@c
\makeatother
```

but with the side effect of executing `\relax` (!), and it's so much less fun...

---

**Footnotes**

1. However, note that if `\relax` were defined by `\def\relax{\relax}`, it would behave completely differently—`\relax` isn't a [quark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493462/do-quarks-have-to-be-defined-as-macros-expanding-to-themselves).
2. It can still prevent ligatures: compare `f\relax f\relax i` with `ffi`.